# Using Replica database instead of using CDC enabled database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I understand that you can't enable CDC on MS SQL DB When having Database replica enabled at the same time, because the replica will override the cdc capture job and disable it, but I am trying to use the CDC feature in my SSIS package using CDC Control task, can I use the replica as my CDC source or is there any other way

*** Please note that I will not be able to use change tracking feature because of performance reasons

Comment: By "replica" you mean transactional replication? If so, CDC and replication can co-exist. The reason that replication disabled the CDC capture agent or because they're the same agent. Running the replication log reader agent will also capture CDC events.

Comment: Yes it is transactional replication, and I read that you can't enable CDC while database replication is enabled because the replication overrides the capture and cleanup jobs

Comment: In SSIS package there is component called "CDC control task" which allows to monitor any table that is CDC enabled, Can I use replication with this component

Comment: What I'm saying is that CDC and replication are not mutually exclusive. In order to use that SSIS component, the table needs to be CDC enabled. Having replication also enabled on a table does not preclude your also having CDC enabled on it.

Comment: Another question, I have a table that is CDC enabled and another lookup table without CDC, If i need to load incrementally and on the lookup (user added new record) what is the best way to load data and apply the effect on the target reporting table, also same case if update happened to the lookup, how to reflect the changes on the target reporting table

Comment: That's in the realm of "ETL is a little bit art". So, the answer to your question is dependent on a couple of things. What springs to mind for me is that if the reference data is small in size (less than, say, 1000 rows), I'd just nuke and pave it every time because that's only likely to be a couple of seconds. But maybe it's large (millions of rows) but mostly static. Some way to detect changes in that data set (whether it be CDC or just a bog standard DateModified column) would be more appropriate. TL;DR - try the simplest thing and if that meets your requirements stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

if you use SQL Server 2016, you can use temporal table .
SQL Server 2016 introduced support for temporal tables (also known as system-versioned temporal tables) as a database feature that brings built-in support for providing information about data stored in the table at any point in time rather than only the data that is correct at the current moment in time. Temporal is a database feature that was introduced in ANSI SQL 2011.
Like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee
(
  [EmployeeID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , [Name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
  , [Position] varchar(100) NOT NULL
  , [Department] varchar(100) NOT NULL
  , [Address] nvarchar(1024) NOT NULL
  , [AnnualSalary] decimal (10,2) NOT NULL
  , [ValidFrom] datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
  , [ValidTo] datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo)
 )
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.EmployeeHistory));
```

Its work very well for save History of `DELETE/INSERT/Update` statement

REFERENCE : [MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION - Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Other guide about Replication, change tracking, & change data capture [Find here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/replicate-track-change-data-capture-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver15)